# Rails 5 - Custom validation with one error message

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to add multiple conditions to valid but i want to view only one summary error message.

```
validates :floor, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { maximum: 2 }
```

How show only one message whenever having any error, like: "Floor is required, must be number..."

In addition, when i use :

```
if @posts.valid?
   @posts.save
   redirect_to room_path
else
   render :new
end
```

Browser will render new with message but url is http://localhost:3000/posts, it is not http://localhost:3000/posts/new This is a problem when user refresh page => it will return index page (not new page). How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write custom validator:

```
validate :validate_floor

private

def validate_floor
  return if floor.present? && floor.scan(/\D/).empty? && floor.length <= 2

  errors.add(:floor, 'Floor is required, must be number...')
end
```

Other question;

When you post the form, the request goes to `create` action. Because of the `create` action, the path is redirected to `http://localhost:3000/posts`. When there is an error in the form, the form is re-rendered with `render :new`. But the url doesn't change because there is no redirect. Actually, there is no error here. This is what it should be.

Comment: Thanks @demir so much ! With the second question, i see that is true, but having any solution this ? (avoid return index action on refresh)

Comment: @RyanTran Actually, it shouldn't go to the index. If you're using turbolinks, this could be a turbolinks bug: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/251